# Safely editing core files

Tags: comments, core, core-modifications

I want to edit wp-comments-post.php so that if for example someone tries to post a comment with no content they will get a popup box telling them they cannot post an empty comment instead of the page redirect that happens at the moment.

```
if ( '' == $comment_content ) {
    wp_die( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: please type a comment.' ), 200 );
}
```

Can someone recommend a safe way to do this to avoid my changes being overwritten with future Wordpress upgrades...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "safe" way to edit core files; if you do you will need to check and repeat the edition after every update. Not recommended at all.

Instead of editing core files, you could use any of the actions and filters available. For example, [pre_comment_on_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_comment_on_post/) (example code not tested):

```
add_action( 'pre_comment_on_post', function( $post_id ) {

    if( $post_id ) {

        $comment_content = ( isset($_POST['comment']) ) ? trim($_POST['comment']) : null;

        if ( '' == $comment_content ) {

            // Redirect to post if comment content is empty
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) );
            exit;

        }

    }

} );
```